# Ionic : Angular animate not working with ion-slide-box, any fix?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ng-animate

I got a view with an ion-slide-box

I include some simple ng-hide animation on a div somewhere in the template

Doesn't work.

I remove ion-slide-box elmt.

It works!

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by replacing deprecated ion-slide-box with new ion-slides